# How to set LIMIT within a conditional statement; POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I want to order the result by id in descending order and then LIMIT the number of rows obtained based on a @condition

```
ORDER BY id DESC
IF @condition is TRUE THEN  LIMIT 1
ELSE nothing
END IF
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT CASE WHEN @condition THEN 1 END;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=23086afef4473d27f4ed769934d8ca97)**

`LIMIT NULL` is the same as omitting the LIMIT clause